# Is this code to delete a node from linked list correct?

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I have written a code to delete a node a from singly linked list. I've tested this code and the output is fine. I am a bit confused about last "else" block in this code. Is it correct?
I mean, how is it that after freeing up the (p->ptr) node, I can still access the node next to it?

```
NODE* delNODE(NODE *HEAD,int position){
        int k=1;
        NODE *p;
        if(HEAD==NULL){
            printf("List Empty\n");
            return HEAD;
        }

        p=HEAD;
        if(position==1){
            p=HEAD;
            HEAD=HEAD->ptr;
            free(p);
            printf("Success!\n");
            return HEAD;
        }
        else{
            while(k<position-1){
                k++;
                p=p->ptr;
            }

             if((p->ptr)==NULL)
             {
                printf("NO such position\n");
             }
             else{
                 free(p->ptr);
                 p->ptr=p->ptr->ptr;
                 printf("Success!\n");
             }
        }
    return HEAD;
}
```

Comment: @pala Doing that too will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not OK. The only reason this appears to "work" is because on those times you've tried it, the memory allocator has marked the memory you've freed as available, but hasn't actually overwritten it or otherwise touched it yet, so the previous value is still sitting there at that memory address. You cannot count on this always being true. For instance, if that node was the last allocated piece of memory in a particular page, there's nothing to stop your implementation of `free()` from removing that from the process's virtual memory table, causing a segmentation violation on your next attempt to access it.

Use a temporary variable instead:

```
NODE * tempnode = p->ptr->ptr;
free(p->ptr);
p->ptr = tempnode;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, and shouldn't. Use an intermediate variable just like in the second if statement where you remove the head node.

Comment: But when I delete a node using this function and print the entire linked list, the output comes out to be correct one. Can you please explain why?

Comment: @2ndGenCore_i5 It is just undefined behavior.